# Remove KeyboardLayout after call LoadKeyboardLayout

Tags: c#, windows, delphi, winapi

how to remove KeyboardLayout after calling LoadKeyboardLayout ?

for example i have installed this [Croatian] KeyboardLayout using this code here:

```
  LoadKeyboardLayout('0000041a', 0);
```

how to remove it programmatically ?
by the way, this KeyboardLayout doesn't appear from the added keyboard languages in windows settings.
i mean is there an `UnloadKeyboardLayout` function ?
i don't mean to remove this KeyboardLayout from hard disk !!
i mean just remove it from the prefered user keyboard layouts list.

Comment: why must every sentence be on a new line? how do you feel when everyone writes in lowercase? why the c# tag? if you would have looked up [`LoadKeyboardLayoutA()`'s manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadkeyboardlayouta) right away you would have noted the "_See also_" section.

Answer (score 0):

OK i solved the problem using this code her:

```
UnloadKeyboardLayout (loadKeyboardLayout ('0000041a', 0));
```

i don't know about this function `UnloadKeyboardLayout`  before.
please go [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-unloadkeyboardlayout)